# How to define discrete Sobolev dual norm so that it can be computed?

Tags: numerical-methods, sobolev-spaces

Suppose I have a real-valued function $f$ defined on the grid 
$$\{ (n, m) : n, m \in \mathbb{Z}, 0 \leq n, m \leq 10.\}$$

How would I define the $(H^1)^{*}$ norm of this function in such a way that it's computable (eg. in Matlab), i.e., the dual space norm?

Comment: It can never be computable, but approximable with an error related to the mesh spacings.